Trying to produce dynamic dropdown list options with label in python dash
I have a dashboard where I'm trying to create a dropdown list that is grouped by and ordered by a database field (CommodityGroup).
The dashboard declaration and callback function are as follows, the options list is created as expected but it is not accepted by the dropdown class.
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Commitment of Traders Dashboard', style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Reporting Entity Type:', style={'font-weight': 'bold'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='rep-ent-type-dropdown',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in pd.read_sql_query("SELECT DISTINCT REP_ENT_TYPE FROM DATA", create_connection())['REP_ENT_TYPE']],
                value=default_filters['REP_ENT_TYPE']
            )
        ], className='dropdown-container'),
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Reporting/Other Total:', style={'font-weight': 'bold'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='rr-other-tot-dropdown',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in pd.read_sql_query("SELECT DISTINCT RR_OTHER_TOT FROM DATA", create_connection())['RR_OTHER_TOT']],
                value=default_filters['RR_OTHER_TOT']
            )
        ], className='dropdown-container'),
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Product Code:', style={'font-weight': 'bold'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='product-code-dropdown'
            )
        ], className='dropdown-container'),
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Market Identifier Code (MIC):', style={'font-weight': 'bold'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='mic-dropdown',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in pd.read_sql_query("SELECT DISTINCT MIC FROM REPORT", create_connection())['MIC']],
                value=default_filters['MIC']
            )
        ], className='dropdown-container')
    ], className='dropdown-row'),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='chart1'),
        dcc.Graph(id='chart2')
    ], className='chart-container')
], className='dashboard-container')

@app.callback(
    [Output('product-code-dropdown', 'options'),
    Output('product-code-dropdown','value')],
    Input('product-code-dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_product_code_options(value):
    conn = create_connection()
    query = """
        SELECT p.CommodityGroup, p.ProductCode, p.LongName
        FROM PRODUCT p
        JOIN REPORT r ON p.ProductCode = r.PRODUCT_ID
        GROUP BY p.CommodityGroup, p.ProductCode, p.LongName
        ORDER BY p.CommodityGroup, p.ProductCode
    """
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    conn.close()

    options = []
    for commodity_group, group_df in df.groupby('CommodityGroup'):
        group_options = [
            {'label': f"{row['ProductCode']} - {row['LongName']}", 'value': row['ProductCode']}
            for _, row in group_df.iterrows()
        ]
        options.append({'label': commodity_group, 'options': group_options})

    return options, value

The error that I get is as follows:
Invalid argument `options` passed into Dropdown with ID "product-code-dropdown".
Expected one of type [object].
Value provided: 
[
  {
    "label": "Environmentals",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "FEUA - EEX EUA Future",
        "value": "FEUA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Freight",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "CPTM - EEX Baltic Capesize 5TC Freight Future",
        "value": "CPTM"
      },
      {
        "label": "PTCM - EEX Baltic Panamax 4TC Freight Future",
        "value": "PTCM"
      },
      {
        "label": "SPTM - EEX Baltic Supramax 10TC Freight Future",
        "value": "SPTM"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Natural Gas",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "G0BM - EEX THE Natural Gas Month Future",
        "value": "G0BM"
      },
      {
        "label": "G3BM - EEX TTF Natural Gas Month Future",
        "value": "G3BM"
      },
      {
        "label": "G5BM - EEX PEG Natural Gas Month Future",
        "value": "G5BM"
      },
      {
        "label": "G8BM - EEX CEGH VTP Natural Gas Month Future",
        "value": "G8BM"
      },
      {
        "label": "GBBM - EEX ZTP Natural Gas Month Future",
        "value": "GBBM"
      },
      {
        "label": "GCBM - EEX PSV Natural Gas Month Future",
        "value": "GCBM"
      },
      {
        "label": "GEBM - EEX PVB Natural Gas Month Futures",
        "value": "GEBM"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Power",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "ATBM - EEX Austrian Power Base Month Future",
        "value": "ATBM"
      },
      {
        "label": "DEBM - EEX German Power Base Month Future",
        "value": "DEBM"
      },
      {
        "label": "DEPM - EEX German Power Peak Month Future",
        "value": "DEPM"
      },
      {
        "label": "F7BM - EEX French Power Base Month Future",
        "value": "F7BM"
      },
      {
        "label": "F7PM - EEX French Power Peak Month Future",
        "value": "F7PM"
      },
      {
        "label": "F9BM - EEX-PXE Hungarian Power Base Month Future",
        "value": "F9BM"
      },
      {
        "label": "FBBM - EEX Nordic System Price Month Future",
        "value": "FBBM"
      },
      {
        "label": "FCBM - EEX Swiss Power Base Month Future",
        "value": "FCBM"
      },
      {
        "label": "FDBM - EEX Italian Power Base Month Future",
        "value": "FDBM"
      },
      {
        "label": "FDPM - EEX Italian Power Peak Month Future",
        "value": "FDPM"
      },
      {
        "label": "FEBM - EEX Spanish Power Base Month Future",
        "value": "FEBM"
      },
      {
        "label": "FXBM - EEX-PXE Czech Power Base Month Future",
        "value": "FXBM"
      },
      {
        "label": "Q0BM - EEX Dutch Power Base Month Future",
        "value": "Q0BM"
      }
    ]
  }
]

I guess I can see that I'm not passing a list of dictionaries properly but I can't see how to change it and keep the effect that I want, which is to have a dropdown list that looks like this:
Environmentals
    FEUA - EEX EUA Future
Freight
    CPTM - EEX Baltic Capesize 5TC Freight Future
    PTCM - EEX Baltic Panamax 4TC Freight Future


The dcc.Dropdown component doesn't support grouped options, you can use dmc.Select from Dash Mantine Components instead, or you will need to flatten the options. Also it's not clear what you are trying to do, in the callback the input value is never used, and it's returned to the output in the same field (output -> input loop).
